# How to resolve this error when using 'LinqPad Driver for Sitecore' with Sitecore 8.1?

Tags: configuration

I'm trying to use [LinqPad Driver for Sitecore](https://github.com/adamconn/sitecore-linqpad) with [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net) application by connecting to Local Sitecore (version 8.1 Update-1).

However I'm getting below error when trying to test connection.

> **Test Connection to Sitecore**
>
> Connection settings are valid for 8.1.0.151207.
>
> This version of Sitecore is not supported by the currently selected
> IAppConfigReader class.
>
> This means that config changes implemented by the IAppConfigReader may
> conflict with your version of Sitecore. This will not affect the
> Sitecore server, but it may prevent LINQPad from being able to
> properly communicate with the Sitecore server.
>
> If you experience problems you may need to implement a new
> IAppConfigReader or extend the one currently being used.
> *[added screenshot below for the same]*

[image: Error in LinqPad Driver for Sitecore]

How to resolve this warning message?

Comment: This is just a warning telling you the driver hasn't been tested with your Sitecore version. In my experience, this will not lead to any problems, so you can safely ignore the warning.

Comment: more info about the warning here: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/getting_to_know_sitecore/posts/linqpad-driver-for-sitecore-1-9

Comment: Dmytro is correct. You can ignore the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source on GitHub - the `Sitecore8AppConfigReader.cs` file, it does a simple check on the version number:

```
public override bool IsSupportedVersion(Version version)
{
    if (version == null) { return false; }
    var min = new Version("8.0");
    var max = new Version("8.1");
    if (version.CompareTo(min) != -1 && version.CompareTo(max) == -1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return base.IsSupportedVersion(version);
}
```

So if you want the message to stop, you would need to fork the code and update that class. Obviously you should test that the config reader for 8.2 is still compatible. If not, you will need to create your own config reader for 8.2.

It should still be compatible, so you do have the option of ignoring he message if you just want to wait for Adam to update the source.